# How to automatically name session in tmux?

Tags: tmux

Provided I have a shell script to figure out name for an arbitrary Tmux session, how to configure Tmux to call it when creating new session (using both `tmux new` and `:new-session`) and use its output as a session name?

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer by chepner, if you are inside tmux then this works

```
new-session ; run-shell "tmux rename-session $(echo testsession)"
```

You can bind this command to a key, say N, for ease like below

```
bind N new-session -s "startname" \; run-shell "tmux rename-session $(echo testsession)>/dev/null"
```

Replace *'echo testsession'* with your command. 
During tests tmux did not allow the obvious 'run "tmux new -s $(echo testsession)"' and returns an error

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script to create a tmux session, name the first window "home", create a 2nd window and name it "download", change it to the download directory and list it's contents, then open tmux attached to this session.  This should show you what you're after.

```
#!/bin/bash
SESSION=$USER

tmux -2 new-session -d -s $SESSION

# Setup a window for home dir
tmux rename-window 'home'

# Setup a download window
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:1 -n 'download' 
tmux send-keys "cd /home/user/download; ls -lh" C-m

# Set default window
tmux select-window -t $SESSION:0


# Attach to session
tmux -2 attach-session -t $SESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `tmux`-specific features for this on the command line, just plain vanilla command substitution in your shell. Assuming your script is called `make-session-name`:

```
tmux new-session -s "$(make-session-name)"
```

There may be a way to do something similar on the `tmux` command prompt, but I don't know it.

Comment: This is what I'm using now, but this doesn't work when I start new session from within tmux with `:new-session`. Hence the question.